# bash: wait for single process from a pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, subprocess, wait

I'm starting 2 processes, where one pipes into the other and then background them both.
I want to wait until the second process finishes to then decide the faith of the first one.

The following snippet gives the output I'm expecting ("exit 1"). However, `wait` seems to wait for both processes to be finished (so 5 seconds), which is not what I want.

What have I misunderstood about `wait`?
How can I make it wait for just the second process in the pipeline and decide to wait for the first one (or kill it) later?

```
#!/bin/sh
{
  sleep 5
  exit 5
} | {
  sleep 1
  exit 1
} &
wait $!
echo "exit $?"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have misunderstood the `wait` builtin behavior. You have misunderstood the shell pipe processing instead.

The `wait` command behaves as expected, it waits for the end of the subshell from the right part of the pipe (the `sleep 1`) and it waits for five seconds because this right part **doesn't effectively terminate** until its **pipe input is closed**. Its pipe input is closed only when the left part of the pipe closes it on its termination (the `sleep 5`), thus after five seconds.

To wait for the right part of the pipe, you can use signal to know when the right part *is about* to finish like that :

```
#!/bin/dash
{
  sleep 5
  exit 5
} | {
  sleep 1
  kill -s USR1 $$
  exit 1
} &
trap "echo \"Second shell finished\";" USR1
wait $!
echo "exit $?"
```

This way, you'll get a signal from the right part and the `wait` command will then only wait until it get these signal (the `wait` command wait for any signal state change, not only termination). The `kill -s USR1 $$` send the USR1 signal to the parent shell. Beware that it can imply termination for the process of the current subshell, you have to know how the process will handle USR1 (i guess `sleep` ignores it).

However, you can't then get the right exit code from the shell of the right part of the pipe, as it is not effectively terminated until its pipe input is closed. To be more precise, you'll get here the exit status 138 which is the the signal status USR1 (value 10) plus the POSIX signal base (128), not the subshell exit status. You can use different signals (USR1, USR2 (POSIX), non POSIX: .. USR64) to *signify* an exit status or use the subshell STDOUT or an environment variable to transmit an exit status instead if required.

Comment: `&` puts the entire pipeline, not just the RHS, into the background. When the RHS exits, that end of the  pipe closes, but the LHS continues until it either tries to write to its end of the pipe (at which point it will receive a SIGPIPE signal, which terminates the process by default) or exits naturally. Once the LHS completes, then the background process finally completes.

Comment: @chepner You're right, however It seems to me that OP question was more about why its `wait` command with a specific PID from RHS subshell doesn't return control when this specific subshell _"terminates"_. Here, the PID is exactly the RHS subshell PID, not the PID of a subshell englobing the entire pipeline.  Do you think anyway that we should add the `&`  backgrounding explanation to the answer ?

Comment: No, `$!` is the process ID of the background process, which executes the entire pipeline. Ignoring any `bash` optimizations involving `exec`, that's a distinct process from the one that executes the RHS of the pipeline. `a | b &` is the same as `( a | b ) &`, not `a | (b &)`.

Comment: @chepner Using a POSIX shell (dash) on a Debian Buster, i get the RHS subshell PID in `$!`, not the PID of subshell englobing the whole pipeline. (I add `echo $!` and `ps -efa` after the `&` to check it). Maybe shell option regarding pipe may change that...

Comment: `dash` may also be using an `exec` trick. (Nothing says that there *must* be separate processes for either side of the pipeline, but conceptually, the `&` absolutely applies to the pipeline, not the RHS. That means the pipe doesn't complete until both sides of it complete, whatever processes might be involved.)

Answer (score 2):

When you write `{...} | {...} &`, there are at least *three* processes involved:

1. The one that executes the commands in the LHS of the `|`
2. The one that executes the commands in the RHS of the `|`
3. The one that executes the entire pipeline

`&` is a *list* terminator. It does not apply to the previous simple or compound command, or even the previous pipeline. This entire command is executed in a single background process:

```
a | b || c | d && e | f &
```

`&` does not apply only to `f`, or `e | f`, or even `c | d && e | f`. It applies to the entire sequence of pipelines.

@KamilCuk mentions named pipes. I would prefer them over process substitution because it allows you to treat both processes uniformly, at least as far as syntax is concerned. (Also, named pipes work in any POSIX-compliant shell, not just `bash`.)

```
mk_fifo p1

{ sleep 5; exit 5; } > p1 & p1_pid=$!
{ sleep 1; exit 1; } < p1 & p2_pid=$!

wait $p2_pid

# Now, kill or wait for the first process as desired
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a pipe, you can create `fifo`s and control each process yourself.

The easiest would be just to use process substitution.

```
{
   cmd2
} < <(cmd1) &
```

Or in the same fashion, using `coproc`ess for the first command if explicit lifetime control isneeded.

Another solution would be to make interprocess communication between the shell in the pipeline and parent shell, be it a signal or just a file, or `pid` could be sent to parent process so that parent can `while kill -0` on just the pid of last pipeline.

```
: > file
... | {
  sleep 1
  echo end > file
} &
while [[ $(cat file) != "end" ]]; do
   sleep 0.1
done
```

Comment: Part of my question is about understanding why wait doesn't do what I expect it to.
process substitution might not be portable to other shells. same for coproc.
And I'd rather not touch the file system. But sure, these workarounds will work :)

Comment: Because it wants for the shell that has run the pipeline to end.

Comment: well, looking at `jobs -l` output, it's clear the `$!` refers to the pid of the second part, not the first. both are direct children of the current process. So where does "the shell that has run the pipeline" come into play when I'm explicitly waiting for just the pid of the second process?

Comment: @MathijsKwik KamilCuk is right, however i added an answer that (i hope) explain a little more the "why" with a way avoiding polling and files I/O.